# Swing Custom Component

Tags: java, database, swing, data-binding

I want to create custom component using swing. Also I want to connect database to that components.

What I want to do,

I want to create a custom `JComboBox`. That combo box name is **warehouse**. Also all warehouses in database should be bind to that combo box.

When I design a form I can use that combo box for warehouse. When I run the program all warehouse will be loaded to combo automatically. Because that combo has internal mechanism to load warehouses.  (How do I write that thing?)

How do I do that?

Comment: By not using a custom `JComboBox` but rather using a utility/factory method to construct such a combobox (or its model) by using the available API of `JComboBox` to customize it. Also note that database connections and Swing components should not be combined on the same thread (see [concurrency in swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial)

Comment: Focus on the model capacities of the Swing components.  You don't need a custom component so much as you need a custom model. You might also like to take a look at [JGoodies Bindings](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/) API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar thing working with a SQL Database.
Working with a database you need to make use of the ResultSet interface to run your query, and Statement class to create a statement.

```
public void makeCombo() throws SQLException{
public JComboBox warehouse = new JComboBox();           
try{
            Connection conn = Connect.getConnection();
            String query = "Select ?? FROM ??";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if (rs!=null){
                while (rs.next()){
                    String name = rs.getString(1);
                    warehouse.addItem(name);
                }

            }
            else{
                System.err.println ("Empty combo");
                warehouse.addItem("Empty Combo");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This should populate the warehouse combo with the results from the query.

Comment: And this example performs database queries on the EDT, or accesses Swing components on a worker thread. Neither of them is a good idea

Comment: I found it a good starting point for learning from. But yes I see what you mean. Just sharing my experience.